# Basic cant get a period where i want it

Tags: python, string, time

I am trying to learn python, i just started to play with datetime commands and i want to put a period at the end of my time like this ex. **Today is 2015-09-17 and it is 09:34:35.**  but it keeps coming out with a space in between the end of the date and the period

```
    import datetime

    date = datetime.date(2021,6,9)
    time = datetime.time(13,30,30,1000)
    print('Today is', date,'and it is', time,'.')
```

Comment: By default print puts spaces between _everything_. Did you try reading its documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use multiple arguments to `print()`, as that puts a space between each value. You can use the `sep=''` argument to remove these spaces, but then you won't get spaces between the other arguments.

Better is to use a formatting method to combine everything into a single argument, so you have direct control over the entire layout. The easiest way is with f-strings:

```
print(f'Today is {date} and it is {time}.")
```

Answer (score 1):

`print` can accept multiple positional arguments. It also has some keyword arguments to tell you how to separate the positionals, and what to do with the output. Specifically, `sep` is the string to place between arguments. By default, it's a space. You can do the following instead:

```
print('Today is ', date, ' and it is ', time, '.', sep='')
```

With an empty space, you are responsible for inserting the spaces where you do want them.

Another way is to build the string you want and print just one argument, so you don't have to worry about the separator:

```
print('Today is ' + date + ' and it is ' + time + '.')
```

This is not the most idiomatic way to do it in Python. The more conventional way is to use string formatting:

```
print(f'Today is {date} and it is {time}.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem: The comma adds a space before the next item.

Solution:

```
    import datetime

    date = datetime.date(2021,6,9)
    time = datetime.time(13,30,30,1000)
    print('Today is', date,'and it is', str(time) + '.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use string concatenation:

```
import datetime

date = datetime.date(2021,6,9)
time = datetime.time(13,30,30,1000)
print('Today is '+ str(date) + ' and it is' + str(time) + '.')
```

Or string formatting:

```
import datetime

date = datetime.date(2021,6,9)
time = datetime.time(13,30,30,1000)
print('Today is {} and it is {}.'.format(date, time))
```